# How to verify attribute text for a validation error message using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to verify that validation errors exist on a page after submitting the page when the fields are not filled in/selected.

I have found that the html shows that the "style" attribute is different when the error displays, so I want to verify that "style" text.

Here is the html from the page:

ERROR NOT DISPLAYED

```
    <div class="errorDiv2">
    <span id="MainContent_ClinicName_mbRequiredValidator" class="errorMsg" style="display:none;">Please provide clinic name.</span>
```

ERROR DISPLAYED

```
    <div class="errorDiv2">
    <span id="MainContent_ClinicName_mbRequiredValidator" class="errorMsg" style="display: inline;">Please provide clinic name.</span>
```

I have been able to find the id using xpath and driver.find_element_by_id, but not the text in the style attribute (display: inline;).

I have used this code, but it finds the id regardless and doesn't find the text in the attribute.

```
clinicNameError = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='MainContent_ClinicName_mbRequiredValidator']['@style=display: inline;']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
clinicNameError = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'MainContent_ClinicName_mbRequiredValidator') and contains(@style, 'inline')]");
```

or by class?

```
clinicNameError = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'MainContent_ClinicName_mbRequiredValidator') and contains(@class, 'errorMsg')]");
```

Comment: I just tried both of those methods and it finds the id under both conditions, but still cannot find the attribute or its value.